# Dataframe group by numerical column and then combine with the original dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame and I would like to first group by one of the columns and calculate mean of count of each group of that column. Then, I would like to combine this grouped entity with the original data frame.

An example:

```
    df = 
    a     b    orders
    1     3    5         
    5     8    10
    2     3    6
```

Group by along column b and taking mean of orders

```
  groupby_df = 

   b      mean(orders)
   3        5.5
   8        10
```

End result:

```
   df = 
    a     b    orders.     mean(orders)
    1     3    5              5.5
    5     8    10             10
    2     3    6              5.5
```

I know I can group by on `b` and then, do a inner join on `b`, but, I feel like it can be done in much cleaner/one-liner way. Is it possible to do better than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `transform`

```
df['mean']=df.groupby('b').orders.transform('mean')
```